# View leaderboard for app in Google Play Games

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I just published in app to the Play Store that uses the Google Play Services API. I setup a leaderboard in my developer console, and can successfully publish scores and display the leaderboard *in game* (along with everyone else's score in my circles, and the public "all-social" leaderboard).

However, when I open the Google Play Games app (or even in my developer console), there doesn't appear to be a way view my leaderboard. Is there a way to view the leaderboard *outside of my app*? Even if it is through the developer console.

Thanks!
Andrew

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The leaderboard can only be viewed in-app, you can only see how many people improved their scores in console and other stadistics.

Comment: Great, thank you. This does not appear to be actually written explicitly anywhere (and I think it would be a good feature to have for developers).

Comment: If I open the google play games app I see other games, which have public leaderboards visible. 

You are right, if you say it can't be shown outside an app, but how can I make the leaderboad visible inside the google play games app? at the moment I can see the leaderboard only in my own app.